# WCF Requests Hanging Infinitely in IIS until Recycled

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

We have been dealing with a troublesome issue with WCF for quite some time, and it has gotten to a point that we are desperate to find a fix.

I have a WCF Service that is hit frequently, approximately 50 requests /second sometimes. Average execution times are 10-20 seconds, but may go up to 45 seconds.

The problem we are having is randomly (we have not been able to recreate for 2 months since it started), when viewing the IIS requests in the worker process, they will just continue to add up and will not complete, and will infinitely increase in time until we have to recycle the app pool.

We have done performance metrics on the DB, and on the code using CPU and memory analyzers and have confirmed that there are no bottle necks in our code that stand out.

I have service throttlign config values set to the following:

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentInstances="800"
                         maxConcurrentCalls="800"
                         maxConcurrentSessions="800"/>
```

I am enabling WCF Tracing right now to see if anything turns up, but its hard because we are unable to recreate.

Comment: Tracing will slow you down even more... 50 requests per second taking 10 to 20 to 45 seconds to execute is pretty significant pressure. Your throttles are also set pretty high for those kinds of execution times. Have you thought about load balancing among multiple web and db servers?

Comment: its already load balancing, and we have ran and been able to handle way more requests so Im fairly convinced its not purely load based on the surface.

Comment: The metrics you're quoting, are they for a single server or all your load balanced servers? If it's a single server, I would suggest adding more hardware to balance out the load.

Comment: Do you think your code could have [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) hidden in it?

Comment: Are you doing any sort of logging? Were you able to determine whether any specific service method(s) initiate the problem?

Comment: How is the service activated?  PerSession (default), PerRequest, Single?  Is there an operation in particular that seems to start hanging, or will any method on the service exhibit the same behavior?  Can we see some sample code, particularly for anything that might deal with mult-threading in your service?

Comment: I had an similar case with way less load.
The service stopped responding, because an background scheduler could not start new tasks. Perhaps it is something like that..

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena it is very possible there is a deadlock, Im in the process of trying to look at potential areas.Mike C It is PerRequest, and there is an operation that causes it, but its impossible to reproduce.Grumbler, Could you provide more info about the problem you had with the background scheduler?